# AnyLogic: Losing of order when al trucks are busy in

Tags: anylogic

We are modelling a supply chain with AnyLogic consisting of supplier->factory->port (all in INDIA)->warehouse (GERMANY) ->retailer (GERMANY).

We are dealing right now with the following issue:

When our retailer orders a specific amout of goods but the warehouse is currently empty the order will be lost. We do not have a backlog where the orders can be "safed for later" similar to an order book in real life.

How can we implement this in our model? Our retailer orders by rate (500,000 / year).

Thanks in advance!

Benj

Comment: Try `Wait` block, or `Delay` until the items are available, triggered with stop delay

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Process Modelling Library and your orders are agents you can make use of a queue or wait block. Have the orders enter the process and then end up in a queue or wait block and then only remove them once you have sufficient stock to satisfy the order.

See example below using a queue block and the code to remove an order from the queue and have it enter the rest of the process flow.

[image]

I created this model from the Product Delivery example inside the AnyLogic example models.

If you are using Java Classes, which IMO is the preferred way, you can simply store them in a collection and then remove them from the collection as needed.

[image]